# How to revert to old value in Rect.js radio button onChange event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, radio-button

I am working on radio button onChange event. once user selects the radio button we show popup with message that really they want to change the option. If YES then select new option if NO then remain on old value. but here in our case the new option getting selecting even after selecting NO option.

Comment: Are you really using jQuery _and_ React together?

Comment: Not using jQuery

Comment: You should add your code as a [mcve]. [Here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002).

Comment: sure let me add